# How to return dropdown value from a separate class inside a Flutter Dialog

Tags: flutter

I would like to add a dropdown (or more in some cases) in a pop up dialog.  In order to manage all dropdowns in the entire app and make the coding of the UI more simpler, I separate the dropdown Widget to another dart file.  I am not able to refresh the UI when the selection of the dropdown is changed, and I am not able to get the value back to the dialog box for future processing.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          ShowDialog(context);
        },
        child: Text('Show Dialog'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<void> ShowDialog(context) async {
  var DataType;
  var DropDownValue;
  await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setStateAB) {
          return AlertDialog(
            scrollable: true,
            title: Text('Test Dialog'),
            content: MyDropDown(DataType, DropDownValue),
            actions: [
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                   // call function to save including the DropDownValue
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.save,
                  size: 24.0,
                ),
                label: Text('Save'),
              ),
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.cancel,
                  size: 24.0,
                ),
                label: Text('Cancel'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
      });
}

Widget MyDropDown(type, val) {
  //get http data according to type
  return DropdownButton<String>(
    value: val,
    isExpanded: true,
    //below items for testing only
    items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
        .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: value,
        child: Text(value),
      );
    }).toList(),
    onChanged: (String? selectedvalue) {
      val = selectedvalue!;
    },
  );
}
```

How can I refresh the UI and return the selected value back to dialog?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass callback function to your `MyDropDown` widget.

```
return AlertDialog(
  ...,
  content: MyDropDown(
    DataType, 
    DropDownValue,
    (String? selectedValue) => DropDownValue = selectedValue,
  ),
  ...,
);
```

```
Widget MyDropDown(type, val, onChanged) {
  return DropdownButton<String>(
    ...,
    onChanged: (String? selectedvalue) {
      val = selectedvalue!;
      onChanged(selectedvalue);
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks debug_ing, the callback works fine, but can you tell how to refresh the dropdown inside the Dialog when onChanged() in my case?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out now, by changing the code to: await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
          void setScreen(val){
            DropDownValue = val;
            setState((){
              DropDownValue;
            });
          }

Answer (score 0):

I see you haven't used the state that you declared in the dropdown menu.all in all this is the gist

```
//update the ui of both inside the dropdown and outside like this
...
onChange:...
setState(() { }); // update the main(state) UI
  setStateAB((){});//update the inner UI

....
```

You could create variable that would hold the value inside both of the states also